# Booting on secondary drive rather than primary drive

Tags: boot

I've got a new Dell Precision 7520 (BIOS setting is Legacy mode; security booting off): the primary drive is a Samson SSD EVO M.2 250GB (on sda) and secondary drive is my Samson SSD Evo 500GB drive (on sdb) which was from my old Dell Inspiron computer (it has some installed scripts and programs which are vital to my work). After many attempts I had to install a copy of my root directory from my sdb drive to sda drive (using clonezilla) to prevent my laptop stalling or needing me to force it to boot in sdb using F12 at boot.

I have Ubuntu 16.04 on both root partitions: one on M.2 SSD at sda5 (a clone of what is on 500 GB sdb5). I’ve changed the fstab on both root directors (sda and sdb) to root for sda5, linux-swap for sda7 and home directory for sdb6 [see fstab.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGyh8.png). I've assigned a different UUID for sda5 than that in sdb5 and refer to that in the fstab. However I have noticed while it is booting it is taking time searching for the boot directory and when it boots it is booting on the secondary drive of the root directory sdb5 not the primary sda5.

I’ve got a screenshots of gparted display of the 250 SSD (sda) [Evo 250 GiB.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8qgG.png) and 500 SSD (sdb) [Evo 500 GiB.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieY2Q.png) as you can see the sdb5 root drive is mounted not the sda5 root drive. I want to use the sda5 root drive rather than than sdb5 to speed up the booting process (the M.2 SSD is faster than the 500 GB SSD).

Something is going wrong which I’m not taking into account. Maybe due to the cloning of the root drives. Got any suggestions of what might be going on and how to correct it?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead, copy-paste the text, and use the formatting tools to make it look nice. This makes it easier for more people to find and read your question. (For more details, see [Why do people post screenshots of their terminals?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/301745))

Comment: From the GParted screenshots, it looks like *both* sda5 and sdb5 are mounted at the filesystem root, but I don't know how that happened.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but from the png files show for me sda5 is not mounted (it isn't locked: it doesn't have a key adjacent to it) while sdb5 is mounted (it is locked: it has a key adjacent to it)

Comment: Yes, you're right, I was reading it wrong.

Comment: I don't understand the question well, but it sounds like you have two identical systems on two partitions, and a Grub *(somewhere, it doesn't really matter)*. So, what you're missing out, is that Grub still thinks you have the system on your previous partition. In this case you're interested in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/266507), points 7 and 8.